# Singleton design pattern example please

Tags: java, singleton

I would like to know an example for singleton pattern like 5 threads trying to access a single text file.At a time only one should be able to read that and that in turn creates a file displaying date, thread name, contents.

```
Textfile- source

 A B C D





Text file - details of the threads and contents

  Date & Time    Thread name   Contents 
  mar 25 10.02         a        A B C D
  mar 25 10.05         b        A B C D
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try to google for 'java singleton example'? There are tons of examples out there. And did you try anything? To me your question is just a requirements specification.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so please add the homework tag.

Comment: In that situation, you would have just one reader thread and have the other threads listen to what was read. Reading a file in multiple threads usually adds a lot of complexity, but doesn't speed up access.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @Peter Mensik.

Indeed, in a multithreaded environnement, the double-check locking solution is broken.
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

The solution (and best practice) is to use the initialization-on-demand pattern :

example at the bottom of this page.

http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/singleton.html

This solution is useful when using JDK 1.4 and older.

In JDK 1.5, you can use enum also.

For better understanding, you can read this excellent article :

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, now I am little bit more wise again:-)